# Jquery: Check if attribute id has specific pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have **6 html buttons**. I am using knockout binding and indexing them differently. Each of them has id as:

```
btnFood-0
btnFood-1
btnFood-2
btnFood-3
btnFood-4
btnFood-5
```

I want to uniquely identify if click was triggered by any of these?

I tried,

```
($(this).attr(id) == btnFood-0) OR ($(this).attr(id) == btnFood-1) 
OR ($(this).attr(id) == btnFood-2) OR ($(this).attr(id) == btnFood-3)
OR ($(this).attr(id) == btnFood-4) OR ($(this).attr(id) == btnFood-5)
```

But its not a good solution. I want to use something like regex to identify it came from some `($(this).attr(id) == btnFood-*)` source.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use `indexOf` for that

```
if ( this.id.indexOf('btnFood-') === 0 ) {
    // do stuff
}
```

or target them specifically

```
$('[id^="btnFood-"]').on('click' ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
if($(this).attr("id").indexOf("btnFood")>=0){
    //YOUR CODE
}
```